# How do I manage zones in my theme in orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm currently trying to create my own theme but I can't figure out how to define zones (for widgets etc).

When I enable the "contoso" theme, a lot of zones shows up, but when it is disabled, all of the zones disappear.

I've tried looking through the "contoso" theme's code, but just I can't figure out how they do it.

PS: I'm using orchard 1.5 rc2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the layout.cshtml file in the views folder, and at the theme.txt file at the root of the theme.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed that Theme.txt file. Guess txt files is not the usual place to go hunting after settings. :)